# How can i point my home server(dynamic ip) to my custom domain

Tags: centos, python, dynamic-ip

I have the online linux centos server.

IN my home i ahve the dynamic ip address.

Is there any way that i can setup something in bash or python so that everytime

i use `home.myserver.com`, that points to my homeserver ip address

Comment: You do not. You point your DOMAIN to the IP - different direction.

Comment: Hi, this question is off topic for ServerFault, please check out our [FAQ] for further details. It **may** be on topic for SuperUser, but check their FAQ first.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your domain registrar this could be easily done.

They could offer the possibility to run a client on your homeserver that updates DNS A entry each hour. I know that OVH offers this feature.

I think you could also use DynamicDNS services (dyn.com, no-ip.com).

Otherwise, you'd need to use bash script with your DNS service, that you'd update…